# How to deny text selection and copying in a div

Tags: html, text, copy, disabled-control

I have this text:

> Hello, you can't select or copy me!

It's in a div, and i don't want people to be able to select or copy it.

Please try to give different languages than js, html and css... Because they can all be edited using the Inspect Element tool.

Code(HTML):

```
<div>
<p>Hello, you can't select or copy me!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Then, in which language do you want it? (as I know the css way)

Comment: AFAIK there's no 100% bulletproof way to do this since the user can manipulate the entire DOM once the page has loaded. There are some workarounds involving CSS and JS that would put off the most basic users, but anyone determined will copy it in one way or another. Why are you tying to do this?

Comment: If i put the text in an image the user could just download the image....

Comment: No matter what you do I could just print screen and grab the text. Even if you really had a 100% bulletproof way to prevent me from copying the text from my browser I could just take a photo of the text. What you're trying to do is pretty futile. Why would you present something to a user that they're not meant to have? Maybe if you answered why you're doing this then there might be an alternative solution. Right now this is an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: In my site you can write stories, and i want to try to prevent others copying others stories, and putting them onto some other site as theirs.

Comment: Then I would say there's nothing you can do to make this 100% secure. The best you can do is try to make it hard enough so that all but the most determined users will be put off. In my opinion the CSS solution would stop most basic users straight away. I'd probably use some JS to prevent right click as well. For advanced users you might look to embed the text in something else like Flash or possibly PDF, although these can still be copied with effort.

Answer (score 3):

Use this CSS:

```
div{
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFIddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/nqc35svv/)

Comment: This is the purpose of the "inspect element tool". You can't hide anything from that tool

Comment: @Jojo01 Inspect element is a developer tool. It shows the current state of the document, and hence you cannot 'hide' anything from it. But as a developer you can choose what to show or hide from the user on the _webpage_